# TailwindCss - Pseudo-classes Pseudo-elements Media queries combine in one class with subclasses

Tags: tailwind-css

**TailwindCss** - Pseudo-classes Pseudo-elements Media queries  combine in one class with subclasses

How combine repeated prefixes in one subgroup.

For example.

According to **tailwind** documentation we should use this peace of code when we want to add styles to disabled input

```
  <label class="block">
   <input type="text" value="tbone" disabled class="mt-1 block w-full px-3 py-2 bg-white
     border border-slate-300 rounded-md text-sm shadow-sm placeholder-slate-400
      focus:outline-none focus:border-sky-500 focus:ring-1 focus:ring-sky-500
      disabled:bg-slate-50 disabled:text-slate-500 disabled:border-slate-200 
      disabled:shadow-none
      invalid:border-pink-500 invalid:text-pink-600
      focus:invalid:border-pink-500 focus:invalid:ring-pink-500
    "/>
  </label>
  </form>
```

I would like to use something like this

```
  <label class="block">
    <input type="text" value="tbone" disabled class="mt-1 block w-full px-3 py-2 bg-white
        border border-slate-300 rounded-md text-sm shadow-sm placeholder-slate-400
      focus:(outline-none border-sky-500 ring-1 ring-sky-500)
      disabled:(bg-slate-50 text-slate-500 border-slate-200 shadow-none)
      invalid:(border-pink-500 text-pink-600)
      focus:invalid:(border-pink-500 ring-pink-500)
    "/>
  </label>
</form>
```

If it's possible  not repeat every time words focus, disabled etc, just use selector once for each component.

Answer (score 0):

Unluckily you can't wrap styles. Some improvements you can do is:

1. Creating "base components" with default styling and then adding only local styling by extending the classes. This approach however is easier when you use JS Frameworks/libraries like react, angular, and so on.
2. Move the commons styles in a CSS file and use [tailwind directives](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives). Then, in your class attribute, you use the class defined in the CSS for the common styling. Then you add local styling using normal tailwind classes.